# swift 4 KVO_IS_RETAINING_ALL_OBSERVERS_OF_THIS_OBJECT_IF_IT_CRASHES_AN_OBSERVER_WAS_OVERRELEASED_OR_SMASHED

Tags: ios, swift

I am having a problem in swift 4. In my controller I have a list and a segmented element that reload the list when it changes, and when I move fast throught the list and then select another segment the APP crash and return this backtrace:

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20)
    frame #0: 0x0000000180dce7e8 libobjc.A.dylib`object_isClass + 16
    frame #1: 0x00000001825383e8 Foundation`KVO_IS_RETAINING_ALL_OBSERVERS_OF_THIS_OBJECT_IF_IT_CRASHES_AN_OBSERVER_WAS_OVERRELEASED_OR_SMASHED + 68
    frame #2: 0x00000001825368ec Foundation`NSKeyValueWillChangeWithPerThreadPendingNotifications + 300
    frame #3: 0x0000000185ba1614 QuartzCore`CAAnimation_setter(CAAnimation*, unsigned int, _CAValueType, void const*) + 156
    frame #4: 0x0000000185ba11ec QuartzCore`-[CAAnimation setBeginTime:] + 32
    frame #5: 0x0000000185b7e804 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::commit_animations(CA::Transaction*, double (*)(CA::Layer*, double, void*), void (*)(CA::Layer*, CA::Render::Animation*, void*), void (*)(CA::Layer*, __CFString const*, void*), void*) + 560
    frame #6: 0x0000000185b7e2a8 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 416
    frame #7: 0x0000000185b7e20c QuartzCore`CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 260
    frame #8: 0x0000000185b7e20c QuartzCore`CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 260
    frame #9: 0x0000000185b7e20c QuartzCore`CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 260
    frame #10: 0x0000000185b7e20c QuartzCore`CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 260
    frame #11: 0x0000000185b7e20c QuartzCore`CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 260
    frame #12: 0x0000000185b7e20c QuartzCore`CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 260
    frame #13: 0x0000000185b7e20c QuartzCore`CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 260
    frame #14: 0x0000000185b7e20c QuartzCore`CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 260
    frame #15: 0x0000000185b7e20c QuartzCore`CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 260
    frame #16: 0x0000000185b7e20c QuartzCore`CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 260
    frame #17: 0x0000000185b7e20c QuartzCore`CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 260
    frame #18: 0x0000000185b7e20c QuartzCore`CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 260
    frame #19: 0x0000000185ae31ac QuartzCore`CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 2148
    frame #20: 0x0000000185b08eb4 QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::commit() + 540
    frame #21: 0x0000000185a5da04 QuartzCore`CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 928
    frame #22: 0x0000000181dec1cc IOKit`IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 392
    frame #23: 0x0000000181b10010 CoreFoundation`__CFMachPortPerform + 188
    frame #24: 0x0000000181b2a96c CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 56
    frame #25: 0x0000000181b2a070 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 440
    frame #26: 0x0000000181b27b44 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2196
    frame #27: 0x0000000181a47fb8 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
    frame #28: 0x00000001838dff84 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 100
    frame #29: 0x000000018b01c2e8 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 208
  * frame #30: 0x00000001021b5d74 Pedidos`main at AppDelegate.swift:15
    frame #31: 0x000000018156a56c libdyld.dylib`start + 4
```

I have seen in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46782372/ios-11-what-the-kvo-is-retaining-all-observers-of-this-object-if-it-crashes-an) that it can be related with the observers, but I am not know how to define the observers declaration in that way. In my controller I have defined two observers for detect the keyboard

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil) 
}
```

And on the viewWillDisappear

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with KVO observation because you're not using it. You're using Notification Center Observation.

Comment: Are you sure you're not observing something inside of a list cell?

Comment: @technerd He's not yelling, it's the line from the stack that tells him there is a problem.

Comment: @JeremyP: Then it's fine.

Comment: Exactly, I'm not yelling. The problem here is that I have using SAP SKD for iOS, and the cells type is FUIObjectTableViewCell, instead of UITableViewCell, that have a defined structure. I'm not sure is inside this cell definition they are using observers

Comment: @inokey and yey there is the message about KVO in the stack trace...

Comment: @user3683466 Have you tried moving the call to `super.viewWillDisappear(animated)` to after removing the observers?

Comment: @user3683466 exactly what I meant. You're using SAP SDK. Just by looking at few properties in FUIObjectTableViewCell, I found this: `Subclass of UILabel, implementing onChangeHandler that is invoked on changes to the value property.` So basically every property of it has it's own observer. The problem is most likely with reuse of the cell and Key Value Observation.

Comment: Not really, I will try

Comment: You are right! The FUILabel implements observers :). I am going to remove this cell definition and use UITableViewCell instead for doing a test

Comment: @JeremyP that is true. Yet, NotificationCenter Observers and Key Value Observers are not related, that's why I suggested the issue has nothing to do with Keyboard notifications.

Comment: It works fine now!! the problem was FUIObjectTableViewCell Thanks a lot @inokey, I'm searching how to give you points but I do not know how to do it, I'm afraid that I can not

Comment: @fenix I will post my comments as answer and you can accept it as an answer

Comment: @fenix I wrote `FUIObjectTableViewCell`, can you share a repro to stan.stadelman@sap.com? :) (also, which SDK version is being used?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notification Center Observation has nothing to do with Key Value Observation, so the problem in a stack trace derived from something else.

If you're using some custom classes for tableViewCells make sure they reused properly.

In your case using `FUIObjectTableViewCell` that has almost every property having their own call back `onChangeHandler` that is according to FUI documentation `invoked on changes to the value property` - basically on KVO.