# Random KVO block crashes when allocating mapView, happens only when open/close screen several times

Tags: swift, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsmapview, google-maps-ios-utils

App is crashing on a map screen when it open and close several times. (Mostly on 6th attempt)

**Class that inherits from `GMSMapView`**

```
class AirportMapView: GMSMapView , AirportMapViewProtocol{

weak var airportMapViewModuleDelegate: AirportMapViewModuleProtocol?

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
 }
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
 }
convenience init(from frame: CGRect, with cameraPosition: GMSCameraPosition) {
    self.init(frame: frame)
    self.camera = cameraPosition
 }
  func setCluster() {

    let algorithm = CustomGoogleMapsClusteringAlgorithm.init();
    mapIconGenerator = VJAirportIconGrayClusterGenerator.init()
    let renderer = VJGoogleMapsClusterRenderer(mapView: self,
                                               clusterIconGenerator: mapIconGenerator!)
    clusterManager = GMUClusterManager.init(map: self, algorithm: algorithm, renderer: renderer)
    clusterManager?.setDelegate(self, mapDelegate: self)

 }
}
```

**In ViewController `viewDidLoad` I am calling `init` method of mapView**

```
self.mapView = [[AirportMapView alloc] initFrom:frame with:camera];
self.mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
self.mapView.settings.compassButton = YES;
self.mapView.settings.zoomGestures = YES;
self.mapView.airportMapViewModuleDelegate = self;
```

**Backtrace of the crash and console logs attached**

[image]

[image]

[image: Backtrace of the crash]

**Observation:**

- `GMUClusterManager` `initWithMap` method if I remove `addObserver` code app is not crashing

Comment: You also need to include any console output related to the crash

Comment: @BaseZen Didn't see anything related to crash in the console 
GSMapView is not releasing it's KVO property may be

If I am creating mapView in ViewController it's working fine , when I create CustomMapView class application will crash

Comment: @BaseZen I attached console logs also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After inspecting the [Google-Maps-iOS-Utils](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils) source code, it turns out that the `GMSClusterManager` class did not maintain a strong reference to the `GMSMapView` that it observed via KVO.  This could potentially cause crashes if the `GMSMapView` object ever deallocated before the `removeObserver:forKeyPath:` method could be called from `dealloc`.

Per [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOBasics.html), strong references should be maintained for objects observed via KVO:

> Note: The key-value observing addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:
>   method does not maintain strong references to the observing object,
>   the observed objects, or the context. You should ensure that you
>   maintain strong references to the observing, and observed, objects,
>   and the context as necessary.

See [this pull request](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/pull/225) (which is now merged) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem then GMSMapView inside my custom UIView subclass

```
var mapView: GMSMapView!
var clusterManager: GMUClusterManager!
```

is deallocated before dealloc in GMUClusterManager and this causes a crash because mapView is going to nil before removeObserver is called
So I added

```
deinit {
    clusterManager = nil
}
```

to my UIView subclass

Check this thread
https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/issues/181#issuecomment-385531638

Comment: Didn't work for me as well as some people commented in the link also 
but removing observer explicitly works for me

Answer (score 0):

Almost the same crash here ... it disappears when i changed clusterManager from strong property to stack object